# Parts of a method inside an NSObject not being executed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsobject

I have 2 classes: AppDelegate and ViewAddFriendsWindowObject.
In AppDelegate.m i have these lines of codes:

```
#import "ViewAddFriendsWindowObject.h"

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    ViewAddFriendsWindowObject *viewAddFriends = [[ViewAddFriendsWindowObject alloc] init];
    [viewAddFriends isFirstRun:YES];
}
```

In ViewAddFriendsWindowObject.h i have:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ViewAddFriendsWindowObject : NSObject 

@property IBOutlet NSButton *cancelSkipBtn;
@property IBOutlet NSButton *doneBtn;

- (void)isFirstRun:(BOOL)firstRun;

@end
```

In ViewAddFriendsWindowObject.m i have:

```
    #import "ViewAddFriendsWindowObject.h"

    @implementation ViewAddFriendsWindowObject
    @synthesize cancelSkipBtn=_cancelSkipBtn;
    @synthesize doneBtn=_doneBtn;

    - (void)isFirstRun:(BOOL)firstRun{

        NSLog(firstRun ? @"Yes" : @"No");

        if(firstRun == YES){
            NSLog(@"YES");
            [_cancelSkipBtn setTitle:@"Skip"];
            [_cancelSkipBtn setEnabled:NO];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"NO");
            [_cancelSkipBtn setTitle:@"Cancel"];
        }

    }
@end
```

Here's the problem. `The NSLog(@"YES")` is executed but `[_cancelSkipBtn setTitle:@"Skip"];` and `[_cancelSkipBtn setEnabled:NO];` are not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you alloc and init an object in code, you are bypassing any connections you made in IB.  Therefore, your IBOutlet properties are not being set to anything before you call `isFirstRun` on it

Comment: so what can i do to [_cancelSkipBtn setTitle:@"Skip"]; be executed?

Comment: You need the view to be loaded from a nib somehow, is it supposed to be a view controller?

Answer (score 0):

In your xib, make sure that you have an object with the class set to `ViewAddFriendsWindowObject` in the identity inspector. Make your IBOutlet connections from the `ViewAddFriendsWindowObject`, then add an `awakeFromNib` method to ViewAddFriendsWindowObject.m. Finally, send the appropriate `isFirstRun` message to `self` in `awakeFromNib` based on a setting in the shared user defaults. Something like this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
   if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"PreviouslyRun"]) {
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"PreviouslyRun"];
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
      [self isFirstRun:YES];
   } 
   else
      [self isFirstRun:NO];
}
```

Comment: Your original code had the same issue. I updated my answer to handle it.